# Trying to find a better approach to custom tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a custom `TabBar`.
My approach so far, was to create one `UIViewController` (Let's call it the `TabBarController`), In the `TabBarController`, I added a `childVC` (Let's call it `UserViewController`).

I couldn't figure out a way to change the `UserViewController` without making the `TabBarController` to disappear.

I started to think maybe this is not a good option, and that there most be a better, actually working way to do so.
All I really trying to achieve is a `TabBarController`, separated from the `UserViewController`, the `TabBarController` will always be displayed on the bottom of the screen, and by clicking the items in it, the `UserViewController` will change accordingly.

I searched for hours, tried different solutions, nothing worked. Really hope you could guide me, maybe share a tutorial or article you have about this.

Comment: What about container view controllers and embedded segues? Would that work for you?

Comment: I would happily try that. Would you share some resources about this? I have never used this.

Comment: check this out, it's pretty informative: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of `UITabBarViewController`.

```
 class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var previousTabIndex: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewControllerOne = ViewController()
        viewControllerOne.tabBarItem.image =  UIImage(named: "one")
        viewControllerOne.tabBarItem.title = "One"

        let viewControllerTwo = ViewController()
        viewControllerTwo.tabBarItem.image =  UIImage(named: "two")
        viewControllerTwo.tabBarItem.title = "Two"

        let viewControllerThree = ViewController()
        viewControllerThree.tabBarItem.title = "Premium"
        viewControllerThree.tabBarItem.image =  UIImage(named: "three")

        let tabBarList = [
            viewControllerOne,
            viewControllerTwo,
            viewControllerThree
        ]

        self.viewControllers = tabBarList.map {
            let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: $0)
            return nav
        }
    }
}
```

And then in `SceneDelegate`, set  `window.rootViewController = TabBarController()`

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = TabBarController()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

If you have created your project in older version of xCode, assign `TabBarController()`  to `window.rootController` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`